# AWS Amplify React Javascript Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser() error because user has not signed-up. (Exact error is "The user is not authenticated")

Tags: reactjs, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I'm learning AWS Amplify React Javascript and building a basic UI chatbot app.  I'm a python programmer and new to javascript and React. I have an awesome backend (AWS lambda functions in python with AWS Lex etc) and now trying to build a basic UI. I am using Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser() to get user id, email and username from AWS Cognito. It works well for existing users, but my code now errors when a cognito user doesn't exist.

My app is working when the user has existing AWS cognito details, but a new user gets an error "The user is not authenticated".

In my javascript I need to somehow add logic to invoke the process to sign-up if the user is not authenticated.  It should be simple, but I'm new at Javascript and cannot quite get it working.

A small snippet of my javascript code which successfully gets the authenticate attributes (but only when user has already signed-up):

```
   import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';
   const { attributes } = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()
   const App = ( ) => {

     const initialState = {
       authoremail: JSON.stringify(attributes.email).replace(/"/g, '')   
     , authorid: JSON.stringify(attributes.sub).replace(/"/g, '')  
     , authorname: JSON.stringify(attributes.name).replace(/"/g, '')  
     , channelid: JSON.stringify(attributes.sub).replace(/"/g, '') 
     , message: ''
     }
```

... then more code

I need to first sign-up the user if await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser() is null.

Can anyone please provide an example of how to force sign-up or authentication when Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser() returns null.

Thanks
Tim

I have tried reading the AWS documentation here :
https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/manageusers/q/platform/js/
but not very clear for a noobie.

And I cannot find basic examples to solve this problem for noobies in React Javascript

Answer (score 0):

Try catch should suffice but this also highlights a flaw with your authentication flow.

You should attempt to sign in a user, if that fails, they should sign up, then after they are logged in, you can then try to get the credentials and they should always exist unless your login/signUp error handing is not designed properly.

On that code snippet you can refactor it as follows:

```js
try{
    Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser();
}
catch(currentAuthenticatedUserError){
   if(currentAuthenticatedUserError == 'The user is not authenticated'){
       //sign User In
        try {
         const user = await Auth.signIn(username, password);
        } catch (error) {
          //if user does not exist, sign up user
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: user:20020135 @Bandisa Masilela
I am not sure how to use your example.  It contains 'await' so I cannot paste it inside the App() function.

Another way to look at my problem is that I cannot correctly use 'attributes' from  currentAuthenticatedUser().

If I remove my code involving currentAuthenticatedUser() then sign-up and sign-in every works, except I cannot acquire user attributes such as email and name.  By adding currentAuthenticatedUser() I am breaking the sign-in.  I cannot find full working complete example code showing how to use currentAuthenticatedUser()